# Neo4j javadocs inheritance hierarchy

Tags: neo4j, javadoc

The Neo4j Javadocs don't contain the inheritance hierarchy of the classes.

For instance, the classes implementing [GraphDatabaseService](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) aren't given on its Javadoc, neither are its superinterfaces-- if any.

I was expecting to see the inheritance hierarchy the way i see in Java APIs for instance-- like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Am i missing anything here?

TIA.

//----------------

EDIT:

Following [tkroman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025784/tkroman)'s useful answer, the next best is to look up the type hierarchy on eclipse(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's intentional. Concrete implementations aren't a part of API in it's original sense of 'interface'. Users are encouraged to access the database facilities via those interfaces in most cases, so there's less space for errors. This applies to all the API docs in general, IMO.